# Memory leak: how to find why object was pinned

Tags: entity-framework, memory-leaks, windbg

I've been struggeling with a memory leak that seems to keep free objects from beeing released.

Recently my webapp started crashing after memory of w3wp.exe reached 1100 MB. In the event log I found a db connection timeout error because the connection pool was full (I set it to 300 connections).

With windbg, doing a dumpheap -stat reveals that there's lots of unreleased objects of type 'Free':

00000071f70ac438   10300    478192918      Free

so 10300 of free objects take up almost 500MB of space.

Doing a !gcroot on a few bigger free objects (plus the size) gives me these:

```
!gcroot 00000071f7d63b78+0x509778
Thread 1bf4:
    000000765f43caf0 000007faab4a7f13 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand..ctor(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)
        rsi: 
            ->  00000071f6cfd0f8 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
            ->  00000071f6cff710 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection
            ->  00000071f6cff738 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter, System.Data]]
            ->  00000071f6cff760 System.Object[]
            ->  00000071f6cff7a0 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
            ->  00000071f826d2f0 System.String

    000000765f43cc60 000007faa65f5832 System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory, System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbCommandTree)
        rbp+8: 000000765f43cc98 (pinned)
            ->  00000071f83aef08 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.ProviderCommandInfo, System.Data.Entity]]
            ->  00000071f83aef30 System.Object[]
            ->  00000071f83aeee0 System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.ProviderCommandInfo
            ->  00000071f6cfc698 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbQueryCommandTree
            ->  00000071f6cfc5b0 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbProjectExpression
            ->  00000071f6cf5f98 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbExpressionBinding
            ->  00000071f6cf5f40 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbSortExpression
            ->  00000071f6cf5de8 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbExpressionBinding
            ->  00000071f6cf5cd8 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbProjectExpression
            ->  00000071f6ced718 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbExpressionBinding
            ->  00000071f6ced600 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbJoinExpression
            ->  00000071f6ceb3f0 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbExpressionBinding
            ->  00000071f6ceb398 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbLimitExpression
            ->  00000071f6ceb340 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbFilterExpression
            ->  00000071f6ceb310 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbAndExpression
            ->  00000071f6ceb2e0 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbComparisonExpression
            ->  00000071f6ceb2b8 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbParameterReferenceExpression
            ->  00000071f826d2f0 System.String

    000000765f43cc60 000007faa65f5832 System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory, System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbCommandTree)
        rbp+190: 000000765f43ce20
            ->  00000071f6ce9fb0 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbQueryCommandTree
            ->  00000071f6ce9f80 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbLimitExpression
            ->  00000071f6ce9e98 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbProjectExpression
            ->  00000071f6ce8100 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbExpressionBinding
            ->  00000071f6ce78f0 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbFilterExpression
            ->  00000071f8273be8 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbAndExpression
            ->  00000071f8273bb8 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbComparisonExpression
            ->  00000071f826d320 System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbParameterReferenceExpression
            ->  00000071f826d2f0 System.String

    000000765f43cf70 000007faa655da7d System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(System.Nullable`1<System.Data.Objects.MergeOption>)
        r12: 
            ->  00000071f6ce2768 System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState
            ->  00000071f6ce7aa0 System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameterCollection
            ->  00000071f6ce7ad0 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter, System.Data.Entity]]
            ->  00000071f6ce7af8 System.Object[]
            ->  00000071f8273b80 System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter
            ->  00000071f826d2f0 System.String
```

Seems like some datacontext with EF gets pinned somewhere. The question is: where and why? My webapp is filled with ef calls.

Comment: Which generation contains your free objects?  You can find out by running !sosex.dumpgen <n> -stat, where <n> can be 0,1,2 or 3/LOH.

Comment: good point, and nice extension thanks. 382MB in gen 0 divided over only 323 objects, and 60MB in gen 2. Is there any way I can see one of those 323 objects?

Comment: !dumpgen 0 -free to see the FREE objects.  !mfrag to see the pinned objects.

Comment: Thanks, with !dumpgen and !refs I got as far as the code in the question above (but a lot faster thanks!). Still I only get to see EF objects and not the assembly/namespace to see where they got created for instance. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you'd like to see.  Maybe I'm just dense.  Could you elaborate? As for why the objects are getting pinned, you can review the code shown in the root frame in !gcroot.  Since the pinned handle is in that stack frame, there has to be some code in there that pins it explicitly or there is some interop code in there.  Also, a much faster alternative to !gcroot is !sosex.bhi, which builds a heap index file, followed by !mroot <OBJ>.

Comment: I'm being vague because I'm pretty new to this ;). How do I get to a pinned stack frame and review the code from !gcroot? Which sos/sosex function does one use for that? And for instance, the second root in the code above says (pinned), how do I get on from there to see the stack frame?

Comment: Use ILSpy to examine the code for System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor, from your example above.  If you see a GCHandle being allocated, then the code is explicitly pinning the object.  If you see the object being passed into interop code, then that's the cause.  Feel free to ping me offline for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about your specific scenario (and I would probably need to see more code to get a better idea) but a lot of people get memory leaks with EF as they hold onto the context too long. EF keeps a snapshot of all of the entities its previously queried for the lifetime of the context to do change tracking.

What i would look out for is that you are disposing of your contexts straight after the query, if you are using `using` blocks around the context this should do this. The fact you have a lot of memory usage and your connection pool is full suggests to me that perhaps somewhere you have a context that's being created and never disposed.

Comment: Thanks, I put those in using blocks exclusively. But it's nice to be sure what is causing it, hence my question.